# Access API Predictif modeling Bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, spss-modeler

I've created a predictive modeling service and uploaded an SPSS stream on it. Now I want to call the API service with Python.

I looked into the API documentation and they don't give a way to do it in `Python` I mean the url of API, json format,etc...

Is there any documentation to help move forward and request the API ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/PredictiveModeling/index-gentopic1.html#pm_service_api Or how to find the specific URL? Or more?